# Как при выборе определенных опций выводить доп. строку?

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать чтобы при выборе в селекторе определенного пункта появлялась дополнительная строка?

[image: скрин]

Comment: отслеживаете выбор селекта и генерируете html, либо же покапзываете уже созданный html по индексу)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id='payment'>
  <option>Выберитие</option>
  <option value='1' data-message='Вы выбрали Web-money'>Web-money</option>
  <option value='2' data-message='Илон Маск одобряет'>PayPal</option>
</select>


<div>
  Дополнительная строка: <span id='message'></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#payment").change(function(event) {
    var message = $('#payment').find(':selected').attr('data-message');
    $("#message").text(message);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let mess = document.getElementById('mess');
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function(){
  /* При каждой смене проверяется - если значение выбранной опции совпадает
  - показываем блок. Нет - скрываем. Такая штука называется "Тернарный оператор" */
  mess.style.display = (this.value == 'Bubu') ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```css
#mess {display: none; color: red;}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option>Выбор...</option>
  <option>Bubu</option>
  <option>Kuku</option>
  <option>Moo</option>
</select>

<p id="mess">Вы точно хотите <b>Bubu</b>?</p>
<!-- Ну здесь может быть и input... или еще что-то... -->
```